# Bluetooth LE For Java SE

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, ibeacon

I am looking for a Java Library that supports Bluetooth LE connections, specifically GATT and if I am lucky Apple's new iBeacon Protocol. It needs to be able to broadcast itself and if possible be able to initiate a connection.

I have seen BlueCove and even gave a shot at extending it to support Bluetooth LE, but could not get it to work. Does anybody know of any supported Bluetooth Libraries that work with Java SE, not for Android or Java ME, because that seems to be all I can find.

Any Ideas?

Comment: also keen to find a Java SE library that does this: did you find anything?

Comment: I have not. Currently I am having to rework y user workflows to workaround this issue.. I would love to find a library for this. Sadly I am not a bluetooth expert nor have the time to write a bluetooth stack.

Comment: how about some JNI and bluez? should be doable.

Comment: @geoaxis I would if I had the time to write a decent library for it.

Comment: Look at this: [https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib](SmartGattLib). It MIGHT help

Comment: Issue is that is for android not for a regular java application which I am trying to do.